# How do you normalize data to feed into a neural network that lies outside the range of the data it was trained on?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, neural-network, normalization

I have an input into a neural network used for classification, that was trained on a data set where the values were from 1-5, for example.  And then I normalized all of this training data so that it was from 0-1.  What would I feed into the network if I wanted to classify something where that input was outside of the 1-5 range.  For example, how could a value of 5.3 be normalized?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways that the value could be handled depending on the conditions of your Neural Network.  Some include:

**1/.**  The Input may be maximised to a value of 1

**2/.**  This may exceed 1 depending on the normalisation algorithm applied and whether the Neural Network was designed to allow it (Typically, if all data was normalised, these values should remain between 0 and 1)

**3/.**  (Classification Only) - If the Inputs are categorical, rather than a quantitative value between 1 and 5, I'm not sure if a value of 5.3 would make sense.  Perhaps adding another neuron for an 'unknown' state may help depending on your problem, but I have a gut feeling that this is overkill.

I am assuming that such a case has arisen as a result of unforeseen future cases being used for estimation purposes after training has been completed.  Generally, handling would really come down to (i) the Programming of the Neural Network, and (ii) the calculation of the Normalised Input.